# how to divide each line on the maximum value in the file.txt and get results as file.txt

Tags: ubuntu, python

I have a file.txt has more 100000 line I want to convert it to a percentage with python, ie to divide each value on a maximum value and multiply it on 100.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each line in the file contains a number, and you already know the maximum value (eg. 300), then the following Python code should work:

average.py:

```
MAX = 300
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for n in f:
        print 100 * float(n) / MAX
```

You can run this with the command:

`python average.py > percentages.txt`

(Note: sending the output to a different file is a good idea, so you don't lose the original data. You can always rename it afterwards.)

If you need to use the maximum value in the file, instead of a known value, then you would need to make to read the file, find the maximum value and then calculate the averages.

EDIT: Just saw the Python tag, so have rewritten my answer. This was my initial suggestion, using `awk`:

`awk 'BEGIN {MAX=300} {print (100 * $1)/MAX}' file.txt > percentages.txt`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your file contains, but I propose my solution:

```
with open(filename) as fp:
    values = list(map(float, iter(fp)))
M = max(values)
[v * 100 / M for v in values]
```